# Getting started with xamarin.forms and Microsoft Azure

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I've been trying to complete the following tutorial from Azure’s documentation:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started/

Which I assumed to be a very simple procedure to follow. But I’ve followed it through several times now, but every time I come to run the complied application downloaded from Azure I get the following error within the .ios build (and the android code won't deploy to the simulator) :

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException         "Internal Server Error”.

I’ve made sure all the packages are up to date etc within Xamarin Studio. and still no luck.

I’ve also attached a screen shot of this error as well:

[image: screenshot]

Within Microsoft Azure I set up the data connection as followed in the tutorial and I chose Node.js for the mobile app backend.

I know its not a Xamarin Studio problem as I've run James Montemagno's Coffee app without a problem. But then again I have also tried to set up the mobile app in Azure to run that app myself following his instructions and just replace the Azure app address within his code with mine and it still doesn't connect to Azure and/or populate the easy table.

So is there a setting or something missing from Microsoft's documentation, that is preventing the xamarin app from properly connecting to the Azure mobile app?

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial are step by step guides I have completed the James montemagno easy tables tutorial and I did not had any problems with it:

https://blog.xamarin.com/getting-started-azure-mobile-apps-easy-tables/

Your error is caused by your web service call, My suggestion is you first follow the complete tutorial to understand it better and then maje changes like the Node.js one.

Or verify your web service response with a tool like Postman.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop

Answer (score 0):

In the debugger, catch the exception and check the Request property to see what the actual REST request is.

Can you make the same call in the browser/Postman?